# Greek letters are not displayed in the chinese text

Tags: fonts, chinese

When I replaced \mathbf{A} with A,$\Omega$ can be displayed,which reasons cause this problem?

---

$\Omega$ doesn't show in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    当我们考虑一束圆偏振光垂直照射时，含时的哈密顿量可以写为$\hat{H}\left(  t\right)  =\hat{H}e^{-iA_{ij}\left(  t\right)  }$,这里的$A_{ij}\left(  t\right)  =\mathbf{A}\left(  t\right)  \cdot\left(  R_{j} -R_{i}\right)$,$\mathbf{A}\left(  t\right)  =A_{0}\left[  \sin\left(  \Omega t\right),\cos\left(  \Omega t\right)  \right]$,$A_{0}$为激光的振幅,$\Omega$为激光的频率。这里我们采用自然单位制，普朗克常数
\end{document}
```

error
    You have requested package `savesym', but the package provides`savesymbol'.

Comment: If I add the `UTF8` option to `ctex` I get no error. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @egreg,you mean Compile code?My Compile code is UTF-8,my Tex distribution is Texlive 2018

Comment: It compiles fine under XeLaTeX. Try using XeLaTeX as your complier or `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}` in your preamble as suggested by @egreg.

Comment: My complier is XeLaTeX.I try to replace \usepackage{ctex} with \usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}, but it doesn't work in my computer.@Huang_d

Comment: @guangya Tried with XeLaTeX (and removed `UTF8`): no problem either.

Comment: @egreg,I tried some of the ways you recommended.Inexplicably,it only worked when I replaced \mathbf{A} with A in my computer

Comment: @egreg,I use \textbf{A} get I want.Thank you for your help